# How to set width for Vaadin Label with empty string

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

[According to the documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/components/components-label.html) if you have an empty Label (a Label with an empty string) the width will collapse to 0. That being said the documentation also says: "If you want a gap that has adjustable width or height, you can use an empty label if you specify a height or width for it" However when I do this the width still collapses to 0. I need the width to keep it's size because I use a different color for the background.

Comment: Have you tried setting a a non-breakable space or some other whitespace?

Comment: Right now I do a check if it's empty and if it is I change the mode to html and add &nbsp;. However this seems convoluted and there must be an easier way when a value is an empty string and you've applied a style to the label (and defined it's width)

Comment: Why do you need to check if it's empty if you know you're gonig to use it just as a separator? I feel we're missing something, so please describe your full scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For me adding style to `whatEverIsTheStyleName.scss` that specifies width works fine:

```
.emptyLabel {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Then simply:

```
emptyLabel.addStyleName("emptyLabel");
```

Setting it in a code like `emptyLabel.setWidth(500, Unit.PIXELS);`
 seems not to work.